# Why AWS and Azure doesn't provide snapshot option to revert the server?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

I have worked with EXSi Servers lot of times.They provide snapshot option which can be used to revert back the same server to any point of snapshot that we taken.

I was unable to find the same in AWS and Azure.These cloud enterprises provide the option to backup the server.

AWS backups the whole volume.

Azure provide vault800 backup wizard which is incremental.

We can create a new Server with that backup, but we cannot revert back the same server.The EXSi Server take snapshot 10% of 100% volume of server and revert back as per our requirement.

Comment: what do you expect as an answer?

Comment: Nothing we can do here but you can add your vote to these suggestions: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines?query=snapshot

Comment: AWS EBS backups are also incremental. And how is restoring a volume from a snapshot not exactly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Azure, take a look at [blob snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-incremental-snapshots).

> Azure Storage provides the capability to take snapshots of blobs. Snapshots capture the blob state at that point in time.

Pretty much the [same story with AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html):

> You can back up the data on your Amazon EBS volumes to Amazon S3 by taking point-in-time snapshots. Snapshots are incremental backups, which means that only the blocks on the device that have changed after your most recent snapshot are saved

Answer (score 0):

how about using a 3rd party backup solution like Veeam or cloudberry to take image based backup copies and replicate them onto preferred cloud storage.
Veeam also supports instant VM recovery, you can immediately restore a VM into your production environment by running it directly from the backup file. Instant VM recovery helps improve recovery time objectives (RTO), minimise disruption and downtime of production VMs. It is like having a "temporary spare" for a VM: users remain productive while you can troubleshoot an issue with the failed VM.